# Why isn't this appendTo working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
 var $sel = $("<select></select>");
 $sel.append("<option>1</option");
 var $sel = $sel.appendTo("<div></div>");
 $sel.insertAfter("#mydiv");
```

HTML:

```
 <div id=mydiv></div>
```

This only appends the select box, but not wrapped in the div.  I would like the select wrapped by another div appended to #mydiv.  I tried:

```
$sel.appendTo("<div></div>").insertAfter("#mydiv");
```

but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$sel` is just the select box, not the thing that wraps it. If you want that too, you can put that in a variable:

```
var $div = $("<div></div>");
$div.append($sel).insertAfter("#mydiv");
```

Or of course there are a dozen other ways to do it, but this keeps everything nice and organized.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/). Try this:

```
var $sel = $("<select></select>");
$sel.append("<option>1</option");
$sel.wrap("<div></div>").parent().insertAfter("#mydiv");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/gHwE4/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine with `appendTo` and no need to use `wrap`, but you are inserting the wrong element i.e. the select instead of the div that has wrapped the select. You need to use `$sel.parent()` with insertAfter()

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/5PCde/)**

```
var $sel = $("<select></select>");
$sel.append("<option>1</option");
var $sel = $sel.appendTo("<div></div>");
$sel.parent().insertAfter("#mydiv");      //Insert the parent of select instead of select.
```